# SPARQL subquery variable scope

Tags: subquery, sparql

I want to compute the visibility of aliens which turns on only when they are outnumbered by humans in the same room with fr:human-1 (it's what this human sees).

I came up with a rather complex query that works fine but seems redundant:

```
SELECT ?actor 
WHERE { 
       ?room  o:contains fr:human-1 .
       ?actor o:in       ?room . 
      {?actor a          o:Human . } 
       UNION
      {?actor a          o:Alien . 
       filter(?aliens < ?humans)   {
                                    SELECT (count(distinct ?alien) as ?aliens)
                                           (count(distinct ?human) as ?humans)
                                           WHERE {
                                                  ?room  o:contains fr:human-1 .
                                                  ?human a          o:Human . 
                                                  ?human o:in       ?room   . 
                                                  ?alien a          o:Alien . 
                                                  ?alien o:in       ?room   . 
                                                 } 
                                   }
      }
}
```

Obviously, some relationships like `?room  o:contains fr:human-1` are traversed twice. I tried returning the `?room` from the inner query so it is used by the outer query and removed the `?room  o:contains fr:human-1` from the outer query. However, this seems to break the pattern as the whole query then returned `?room` values that were not returned by the subquery. As I've figured this is because the `actor o:in       ?room .` relationship matches not only the precomputed `?room`.

Now I am wondering if I can instead return `?human` and `?alien` from the subquery and then combine them into the `?actor` variable somehow in the outer query.

Comment: BTW, see section 2 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.01441.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you said what you are trying to return?

It looks like your returning a list of actors playing humans, and a list of actors playing aliens, but only if there's less aliens than humans - is h

You have o:contains, and o:in, which seems redundant, surely you could use o:contains and reverse the subject and object?

Comment: That's right. I compute the visibility of aliens which turns on only when they are outnumbered by humans in the same room with `fr:human-1` (it's what this human sees). Yes, `o:contains` is defined as an inverse of `o:in` and while being redundant it at least doesn't incur multiple computations.

Comment: I wish I could eliminate code duplication from the outer query using the results computed in the subquery, like the `?room`.

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer seems to be "there's no way to eliminate redundancy in this complex query other than splitting it".